# Convertir un archivo excel de varias hojas a un archivo XML con un formato determinado con c#

Tags: c#, excel, xml

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto de un programa que convierte archivos xlsx o Excel a archivos tipo XML. Por el momento he logrado que el archivo excel sea guardado y al momento de convertirlo a xml se convierte a xml, pero no transforma la información data del excel: solo se pone el título de la primer celda.
¿Alguien sabe cómo ponerle un plantilla o algo para que se pase la información a xml?

Este es el código que tengo para crear el archivo xml:

```
    public bool CreateXltoXML(string XmlFile, string XlFile, string RowName)
    {
        bool IsCreated = false;
        try
        {
            DataTable dt = GetTableDataXl(XlFile);
            XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(XmlFile, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
            writer.WriteStartDocument(true);
            writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
            writer.Indentation = 2;
            writer.WriteStartElement(RowName);
            List<string> ColumnNames = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().ToList().Select(x => x.ColumnName).ToList(); // Lista de los nombres de la columna
            List<DataRow> RowList = dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().ToList();
            foreach (DataRow dr in RowList)
            {
                writer.WriteStartElement(RowName);
                for (int i = 0; i < ColumnNames.Count; i++) // Obtener nombre de nodos de la columnas del DATATABLE
                {
                    writer.WriteStartElement(ColumnNames[i]);
                    writer.WriteString(dr.ItemArray[i].ToString());
                    writer.WriteEndElement();
                }
                writer.WriteEndElement();
            }

            writer.WriteEndElement();
            writer.WriteEndDocument();
            writer.Close();
            if (File.Exists(XmlFile))
                IsCreated = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }

        return IsCreated;

    }
```